# Recursive Permutation, Ellis Horowitz Algorithms and data structure Confusion.

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, recursion, non-recursive

I am a beginner programmer in my first year of university. My tutor has asked us to do some research on a recursive algorithm and make it none recursive. No natter how much I try it seems impossible. 
The question reads

> A is a character string (e.g. A =  "hello") and interchange, which is
>   an            abstraction, exchanges the k-th with the i-th character of A, 
>   e.g. CALL         interchange("hello", 2, 3) would change "hello" to
>   "hlelo").

The idea is to print out all the possible permutations
The version in c++ reads

```
void perm(char*a, const int k, const int n)
{
  if(k==n)
  {
    cout << a;
  }
  else
  {
    for (i=k;i<=n;i++)
    {
      interchange(a, k, i);
      perm(a, k+1, n)
    }
  }
 }
```

My tutor much prefers to use a language called ADL that seems only to appear in the Horowitz book "algorithms and data structures". He has posed the question in ADL so I will add that code in too, its very easy to understand.

```
proc perm(IN a, IN k, IN n)
  if k=n then
    print(a)
  else
    {
     for i <- k to n do
       call interchange(a,k,i)
       call perm( a, k+1, n)
     end
    }
end
```

thanks for anyone who can help.
Martyn

Comment: Any recursive algorithm can be converted to an iterative form by wrapping everything in a while loop and using a stack structure to track the "recursion".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive algorithm is simply an algorithm that *uses a stack*.

The recursion allows you to use the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) as your data stack.

Any recursive function taking this form:

```
void perm(char*a, const int k, const int n)
{
   // check if your code should return

   // make a recursive call with new data
}
```

Can be changed to this:

```
void perm(char*a, const int k, const int n)
{
   // Create a stack, push (a,k,n)

   while ( /* stack isn't empty */ )
   {
       // check if stack should be *popped* (instead of returning)

       // Put new data on the stack (instead of recursing)
   }
}
```

Comment: What you've given there is actually tail-recursive (and so doesn't need a stack at all).  What about if there's something **after** the recursive call in the original function?

Comment: @user2237577 which book of Horowitz do you cite exactly?

Comment: @cf16 The book is "Fundamentals of Data Structures" from 1976. The algorithm is from there but I do not think the questions are.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint, without doing your homework for you. As you walk down the string, looking at the ith character, you're in one of three possible states:

- i == k
- i == n
- else

What do you print in each of those three cases?